# correct way to check if nullable has a value

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, nullable

assuming **v** is a nullable, I'm wondering what are the implications / differences between these usages:

VB:

1. **If v Is Nothing Then**
2. **If v.HasValue Then**

C#:

1. **if (v == null)**
2. **if (!v.HasValue)**

Comment: @BoltClock, the question you linked to is a C# question. This question, judging from the code, is about VB.NET. The two languages do have different wrinkles around nullable types, so I wouldn't call this a duplicate.

Comment: @Joe White: Never knew - thanks for pointing that out. Should zap my auto-link comment...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no difference - `Is Nothing` is compiled to use `HasValue`. For example, this program:

```
Public Class Test
    Public Shared Sub Main()
        Dim x As Nullable(Of Integer) = Nothing
        Console.WriteLine(x Is Nothing)
    End Sub
End Class
```

translates to this IL:

```
.method public static void  Main() cil managed
{
  .entrypoint
  .custom instance void [mscorlib]System.STAThreadAttribute::.ctor() = ( 01 00 00 00 ) 
  // Code size       24 (0x18)
  .maxstack  2
  .locals init (valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<int32> V_0)
  IL_0000:  ldloca.s   V_0
  IL_0002:  initobj    valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<int32>
  IL_0008:  ldloca.s   V_0
  IL_000a:  call       instance bool valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<int32>::get_HasValue()
  IL_000f:  ldc.i4.0
  IL_0010:  ceq
  IL_0012:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(bool)
  IL_0017:  ret
} // end of method Test::Main
```

Note the call to `get_HasValue()`.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference. You always get the same result.
Some time ago I wrote a few unit test that check different behaviors of nullable types: http://www.copypastecode.com/67786/.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely no difference. This is just your style preference.

Those two lines of code will generate absolutely identical IL code:

```
if (!v.HasValue)

if (v == null)
```

You can see in IL that in both cases Nullable::get_HasValue() is called.

Sorry, I did the sample in C#, not VB.

Answer (score -1):

Use the `HasValue` property

```
If v.HasValue Then
    ...
End
```

Comment: Could you justify your answer?